# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation thrown when scaffolding a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, scaffold

I created a separate Class Library project to store the Database Context and Model Classes.
In the same solution, I created an ASP.NET MVC project and referenced the Class Library project, as well as include the Connection String for the Database Context, in the project's Web.config file.

However, when I attempt to add a Controller (with views, using EF), I get the following error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I am able to see the Database Context and Model Classes in the Add Controller drop down boxes, so I don't think its a referencing issue.

If anyone is also experiencing this error (with this configuration), you assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem when my context contained collections that were accidentally declared with `List` instead of `DbSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just checked them over and they are all declared using DbSet. 
The thing is, I have another "Windows Service" project in the same solution, referencing the same Class Library without issue.

Comment: Here's a couple cases of similar problems with some things to try. One of those things that could probably be a dozen different problems: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23576294/84206 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/23910162/84206

Comment: Thanks! Checking them out now...

Comment: Thanks alot Aaron! Found the solution in one of the links you posted (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24154061/3315406). I had more than one ConnectionStrings define. I removed the default and replaced it with the ConstringStrings from my Class Library. Works fine now :D

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I'm going to flag this as duplicate and add link to that question. For anyone who might find this question in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application can't scaffold items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576294/application-cant-scaffold-items)

Comment: @Noximus: Good to see you have fixed this. Do us a favour, create a good answer with the solution and mark as answered. It takes the question off the unanswered list and helps us out when looknig for questions to answer. Good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had more than one ConnectionStrings define. I removed the default and replaced it with the ConstringStrings from my Class Library. Works fine now!

Solution taken from the following post: [Application can't scaffold items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576294/application-cant-scaffold-items/24154061#24154061)

Comment: In my case i changed connection string name parameter from `MyDbContext("connectionString")` to `MyDbContext("name=connectionString")`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In my case, I had the Configuration block declared twice in the Web.config file. After I removed one the scaffolding worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I fixed the version of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** to match **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**. It was a version mismatch after all!