# Non-descriptive error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm working with MVC 5, I've created a Products model (Entity Framework code-first) and when I try to add a Products controller I select my items like so:

[image]

Then when I click Add I get the following error:

[image]

Anyone ran into this before? Do I have to uninstall VS 2013 and re-install it?

**EDIT**

@DeJaVo I followed everything from the post you supplied and now I'm getting this error:

[image]

I've rebuilt the project and the error persists.

Comment: which version of entity framework you have and which version of vs2013 you have?

Comment: @DeJaVo it's Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Entity Framework 5

Comment: As I know you should upgrade entity framework 6 to overcome this issue...

Comment: Also I've found lots of question on the manner, one of them seems very useful - have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576294/application-cant-scaffold-items

Comment: @DeJaVo I upgraded to 6.1.3 and still same error