# Add Controller using Entity Framework doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on my first MVC project following along with the book C# 6.0 and .NET 4.6 framework by Andrew Troelsen and Philip Japikse.
In my solution there are two projects one for the MVC application and the other for the Data Access Library,

When I add a new controller with view, using EF
I get this error:

[image]

> there was an error running the selected code generator: exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation

There are many questions on this issue, I tried every possible solution:

- I moved the ConnectionString to a separated config file
- I cleared the cache folder
- I don't have OnModelCreating in the context class
- I have the same version of EF installed on the two projects and they both
  using .NET 4.6.1.

for testing purpose, I created a new EF module in the DAL project (created the entity class and the context class) and when I added a Controller I got an error (Message box error) says that it can't find the connection string in the app config, (i'm alitle newbie to the MVC) I moved it from the web.config to the app.config, I got the same error, I moved it back, keep it in the two config files, and it works, and the scaffolding done successfully (I don't understand why I should keep the same connection string in the app.config and the web.config files!).
I revised the connection string in for my Modules which causes the error, and nothing different I noticed:

here is the App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AutoLotConnection" connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=AutoLotEF;integrated security=True;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyCon" connectionString="data source=.; initial catalog= AnotherDB; integrated security=true;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVCTest-20160910010148.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVCTest-20160910010148;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="MyCon" connectionString="data source=.; initial catalog= AnotherDB; integrated security=true;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="AutoLotConnection" connectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=AutoLotEF;integrated security=True;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  <add name="ModelTest" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=MVCTest.ModelTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

this is the Inventory class for the Model:

```
[Table("Inventory")]
    public partial class Inventory
    {
        [Key]
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Make { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PetName { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new HashSet<Order>();
    }
```

the context class:

```
public class AutoLotEntities : DbContext
    {
        static readonly DatabaseLogger DatabaseLogger = new DatabaseLogger("sqllog.txt", true);
        public AutoLotEntities()
            : base("name=AutoLotConnection")
        {
            //DbInterception.Add(new ConsoleWriterInterceptor());
            DatabaseLogger.StartLogging();
            DbInterception.Add(DatabaseLogger);
        }
        public virtual DbSet<CreditRisk> CreditRisks { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576294/application-cant-scaffold-items

Comment: Yes, doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the `DatabaseLogger` lines in the context class, and this resolved the issue!

```
//static readonly DatabaseLogger DatabaseLogger = new 
DatabaseLogger("sqllog.txt", true);

       public AutoLotEntities()
            : base("name=AutoLotConnection")
        {
            //DbInterception.Add(new ConsoleWriterInterceptor());
            //DatabaseLogger.StartLogging();
            //DbInterception.Add(DatabaseLogger);
        }
```