# Incomplete Scaffolding in an ASP.Net 2.x Core / RazorPage + an existing (empty) DB

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core-2.0, scaffolding, razor-pages

I am learning / playing with ASP.Net Core 2.x with Razor Pages.  I am using an SQLite Db with Tables already created but all of them are empty.  I am going by the Tutorial @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model but have digressed in the following steps:

1. I followed the instructions @ https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db in order generate the scaffolding code for a single table with just 2 columns, from my already created SQLite Db file
2. I didn't perform the "Initial Migration" as in the 1st link (...razor-pages/model) since I am not creating the DB from the Model in C# Code

Everything is generated as expected but even after a Create New record from my WebSite (.../WebApplication1/ClientTags/Create), the .../ClientTags page doesn't show the record even though the record has indeed been saved to the SQLite Db file.

My disappointment is, the above Tutorials seem to indicate that all the necessary code for the basic CRUD ops (particularly listing of records) would be generated by the Scaffolding Tool (aspnet-codegenerator) which seems not the case for me.  Is it the expected behaviour or am I being lazy and expecting too much from Microsoft?

I am using VS2017 15.6.1 Community on Windows10 Pro v1709 build 16299.248 and .Net Core v2.1.100 - the latest of everything as of this posting.

Thanks in advance.

rgds,
Vatsan

Comment: You can give Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design nuget packet a shot. The said nuget packet resolved the said issue for me.
Here are some links that might be helpful to you. If the nuget packet I suggested does not do the trick
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576294/application-cant-scaffold-items
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165185/mvc4-scaffolding-add-controller-gives-error-unable-to-retrieve-metadata
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992599/cant-add-view-from-controller-in-vs-2015-there-was-an-error-running-the-sele